# XCode 6 - Navigation Bar width Button

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, ios8

I have an "Any Any" View Controller. There I placed a Navigation Bar and set "Horizontal Center in Container". Now it's in the middle of my View.
But when I place a Bar Button Item on the right hand side of the Navigation Bar, it only disappears in landscape on my iphone 5s. How can I set the width of the Navigation Bar to 100%?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no Auto Layout expert, but this works for me.  You should have 3 constraints for your Navigation Bar:

1. Trailing Space to Superview
2. Leading Space to Superview
3. Top Space to Superview

These should all have constants of zero.

This process worked for me:

1. Delete the constraints for the Navigation Bar
2. Select the Navigation Bar in the Document Outline
3. Click the Resolve Auto Layout Issues button `|-^-|` and select `Add Missing Constraints`.